# Erro Dart/Flutter: 'context != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou tentando aplicar um alerta de dialogo toda vez que o item for duplicado mas quando eu faço o teste ele acaba dando este erro, alguem tem alguma dica de como arrumar isso ?

```
 void SalvarMensagem() async {
    // select id_armarios from armarios where numero_serie = '$_numeroSerie'

    this._status = _status;
    _numeroSerie = _status.substring(48, 80);

    final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
        .collection("lockers")
        .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments());

    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    if (documents.length == 1) {
      duplicado(context);
    } else {
      await Firestore.instance
          .collection("lockers")
          .document()
          .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie});
    }
  }

duplicado(BuildContext context){
  Alert(
    context: context,
    type: AlertType.error,
    title: "QR Code já cadastrado",
    buttons: [
      DialogButton(
        child: Text(
          "OK",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        width: 120,
      )
    ],
  ).show();
}
```

Error:

> E/flutter ( 9129): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]
>   Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart':
>   Failed assertion: line 446 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true.

Comment: De onde vem  `context` em `SalvarMensagem`?

Comment: vem da função duplicado(title: "QR Code já cadastrado")

Comment: A mensagem de erro informa que `context` é nulo (null), acredito que `context` deve vir do `widget` que chama `SalvarMensagem` e então deve ser passado para `duplicado`

Answer (score 1):

No método salvar mensagem tu está chamando a função duplicado e está passando o context por parâmetro, mas onde está o contexto, a definição dele?

Toda vez que tu precisar o context em algum código do flutter tu precisa 'usar' ele de dentro do estado principal, aquele método que retorna o widget da tela.

Eu sei que a pergunta é antiga mas eu respondendo aqui poderá ajudar outros.